# Update JSONB column data from other columns in same table

Tags: json, postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

In **Postgres 9.5** I want to update a column with data from other columns in the same table. The issue is with `""` signs because inside the JSON string it is not allowing to read data from actual column:

```
CREATE TABLE sample_table(
   id bigint
 , revision integer
 , var_data text
 , json_result jsonb
);
```

Sample data:

```
id  revision  var_data  json_result
1     10        test_A   {"EstimatedResult": 10, "RevOnly": 10}
2     20        test_B   {"EstimatedResult": 20, "RevOnly": 20}
3     30        test_C   {"EstimatedResult": 30, "RevOnly": 30}
```

**Example 1: This is working:**

```
UPDATE "public"."sample_table"
SET "json_result" = "json_result" - 'EstimatedResult'
                  || jsonb_build_object('EstimatedResult', revision::numeric)::jsonb
WHERE json_result->>'EstimatedResult' IS NOT NULL;
```

Resulting `json_result`:

```
{"EstimatedResult": 10, "RevOnly": 10}
{"EstimatedResult": 20, "RevOnly": 20}
{"EstimatedResult": 30, "RevOnly": 30}
```

**Example 2: THIS FAILED TO WORK:**

The requirement is to modify the json structure to insert data from multiple columns. The result should be like this:

```
{"EstimatedResult": {"revid": 10, "displ": "test_A"}, "RevOnly": 10}
{"EstimatedResult": {"revid": 20, "displ": "test_B"}, "RevOnly": 20}
{"EstimatedResult": {"revid": 30, "displ": "test_C"}, "RevOnly": 30}
```

I know how to force data from colums in "RevOnly" using the Example1.
However, I have no success forcing data from columns is "revid" and "displ"

I had success generating JSON value but the result was like this:

```
{"EstimatedResult": {"revid": "revision", "displ": "var_data"}, "RevOnly": 10}
{"EstimatedResult": {"revid": "revision", "displ": "var_data"}, "RevOnly": 20}
{"EstimatedResult": {"revid": "revision", "displ": "var_data"}, "RevOnly": 30}
```

Note "revision" and "var_data" are not updated.

How to update properly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming **at least Postgres 9.5** and data type **`jsonb`**.
One elegant way is with [`jsonb_set()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE) - combined with `jsonb_build_object()` you've already used successfully:

```sql
SELECT jsonb_set(json_result
               , '{EstimatedResult}'
               , jsonb_build_object('revid', revision, 'displ', var_data)
                )
FROM   sample_table;
```

Comment: Thank you Erwin. Yes it worked, it is PG 9.5 and yes it is `::jsonb`

Answer (score 0):

This `UPDATE` command did exactly what I was looking for.
In case someone needs it.

```
UPDATE public.sample_table SET json_result =
       jsonb_set(json_result
               , '{EstimatedResult}'
               , jsonb_build_object('revid', revision::numeric, 'displ', var_data::text)) 
 WHERE json_result->>'EstimatedResult' IS NOT NULL
 RETURNING *;
```